# DigitalOcean Spaces - File Upload Using Curl

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload some files to DigitalOcean's Spaces with PHP and cURL but for some reason I cannot do it. I don't want to use some libraries like Amazon's SDK because they are too big. I want something more simple. 
Here is where I am at now.

```
    $file = '/home/development/www/source.png';

    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $filesize = filesize($file);

    $accessKeyId = '###';
    $secretKey = '###';

    $longDate = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
    $shortDate = gmdate('Ymd');

    $newfile = urlencode('/new-dir/new-file.png');

    $cannonical = 'PUT'.PHP_EOL.''.$newfile.''.PHP_EOL.''.PHP_EOL.'content-length:'.$filesize.''.PHP_EOL.'host:fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com'.PHP_EOL.'x-amz-date:'.$longDate.''.PHP_EOL.'x-amz-acl:public-read'.PHP_EOL.'content-length;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-acl;'.PHP_EOL.''.hash_file('sha256', $file).''.PHP_EOL.'';

    $cannonical = hash('sha256', $cannonical);

    $string = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'.PHP_EOL.''.$longDate.''.PHP_EOL.''.$shortDate.'/fra1/s3/aws4_request'.PHP_EOL.''.$cannonical.''.PHP_EOL.'';

    $signingKey = hash_hmac('sha256', $shortDate, 'AWS4'.$secretKey, true);
    $signingKey = hash_hmac('sha256', 'fra1', $signingKey, true);
    $signingKey = hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', $signingKey, true);
    $signingKey = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $signingKey, true);
    $signature  = hash_hmac('sha256', $signingKey.$string, $signingKey);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/'.$newfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Length' => $filesize,
        'Host' => 'bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
        'x-amz-date' => $longDate,
        'x-amz-acl' => 'public-read',
        'Authorization' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential='.$accessKeyId.'/'.$longDate.'/fra1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-acl;content-length, Signature='.$signature
    ]);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contents);
    curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $http_code;
```

Every time I try to upload something it says 403 Forbidden. Most likely I don't generate the Authorization correctly but I'm not sure what I do wrong.